# Importing relationship records in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0: missing converse relationship column

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm using the [built-in data import tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150977.aspx) in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 to import some [Customer Relationship](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd903934.aspx) records.  I've created a .csv import file with the following fields:

- Party 1
- Party 2
- Role 1
- Role 2

I specify this file, and because I've used the display names for the attributes in the import file, the attributes are mapped automatically by the import tool.  However, I then get an "unmapped mandatory column" error message.  The error detail reveals that it is the "Converse Relationship" field that is missing.

I'm not sure how I'm expected to supply this, since at this point, I haven't imported any records yet!  Has anyone figured out a way to work around this and import customer relationship records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is add a column at the end called Converse Relationship (case sensitive) this will now work